# countably compact

Tags: general-topology

if $(X,\tau)$ is not countably compact.
is the below topology $T_1$ space and countably compact?

$$\mu = \{U\in\tau:p\notin U\}\cup\{U\in\tau: p\in U\text{ and }X\setminus U\text{ is countably compact in }(X,\tau)\}$$

Comment: Once again you posted without proofreading. I think that I was able to guess what the missing symbols were supposed to be, but you should check. You cannot rely on others to guess what you were trying to ask.

Comment: You didn’t say, but I assume that $p$ is some fixed point of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly $\langle X,\mu\rangle$ need not be $T_1$ if $\tau$ is not $T_1$. If $\tau$ is $T_1$, then $\mu$ is $T_1$; to see this, just show that for each $x\in X$, $\{x\}$ is closed in $\langle X,\mu\rangle$. HINT: Finite sets are always compact.

To show that $\langle X,\mu\rangle$ is countably compact, proceed in the most straightforward fashion: let $\mathscr{U}$ be a countable $\mu$-open cover of $X$. There must be some $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $p\in U_0$. Clearly $\mathscr{U}\setminus\{U_0\}$ is a $\mu$-open cover of $X\setminus U_0$. What do you know about the set $X\setminus U$?